# Is there any link to download ab Apache benchmark

Tags: windows, apache

Can anyone please provide me the direct to download the Ab.exe Apache benchmark utility?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just download Apache (www.apache.org).  It comes with it  (in ApacheX.X/bin)

...Guessing (from one of your other questions) that you're using a Mac... there appear to be instructions here:
http://switch.richard5.net/isp-in-a-box-v2/installing-apache-on-mac-os-x/

(if not, I can probably help with a Windows installation, but in general, Google is your friend!)

A list of mirrors for the windows binaries can be found [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html#down).

There are some basic instructions here:
http://www.ricocheting.com/how-to-install-on-windows/apache

...basically, install it, and the ab.exe will be in the 'bin' subdirectory of the installation

Comment: Can u please tell me the steps how to go with it.

Comment: Yup ur guess is right that I am using mac machine.But I need the download for windows machine.I googled for it but I didn't found any direct links to download it.

Answer (score 31):

On Ubuntu, I can install ab without installing all of Apache via the apache2-utils package. So:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-utils
```

Answer (score 5):

TMB nailed it with the link to [XAMMP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#641) in the following question : [How to install apache bench on windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327099/how-to-install-apache-bench-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 5):

For *Windows Users* there is no direct binary download.

One has do install the Apache server via the msi setup package, grab ab.exe from the Program Files/Apachge Group/bin folder and uninstall Apache again.

link to the msi package I used was once here:

http://mirror2.klaus-uwe.me/apache//httpd/binaries/win32/httpd-2.0.65-win32-x86-no_ssl.msi

but this is 404 as of today.

http://mirror2.klaus-uwe.me/apache//httpd/binaries/win32/

might help.

Comment: This link 404s now.

Answer (score 4):

Download the Apache MSI-package (https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi -> Binaries for the version you want -> win32 directory -> httpd-...-win32-x86-no_ssl.msi), open this .msi file with [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), find ab.exe, select it, and copy it to wherever you want.

I've just done that with `http://.../httpd/binaries/win32/httpd-2.2.25-win32-x86-no_ssl.msi`, and it works for me.

Comment: I did the same, downloaded the binaries (2.4.25) from https://www.apachelounge.com/download/, then extract, copied /bin/ab.exe to another folder, started a cmd and it worked.

Comment: Thanks @CedricDumont so much easier on this link!

Answer (score 2):

CentOS and Fedora users can find Apache Benchmark in package `httpd-tools`.

Example:

```sh
# CentOS
sudo yum install httpd-tools
# Fedora
sudo dnf install httpd-tools
```

Use installed Apache Benchmark binary as `ab`.

Answer (score 1):

Get the .msi from archive site:

http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/binaries/win32/

once installed, go to your Windows explorer to the installation path like:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin\ab.exe

Comment: The newest files in this folder are as old as 2009. Perhaps some context (what IS this archive and what ARE those versions of Apache) would be helpful, especially since your answer is from 2021.