# Add https support to Apache Bench on Windows

Tags: windows, https, apachebench

I have Apache server 2.2.15 on my Windows 7 machine and I want to run Bench on a server I have using https. But when I run `ab [myopts] https://example.com`, I get `SSL not compiled in; no https support`. From what I've read you can compile ab with https support with a flag during the server install.

My question is, considering I already have server installed, what is the easiest/best way to benchmark my server over https?

Answer (score 85):

Use the abs.exe tool to test sites with a SSL cetificate

Comment: Because I did not compile with https support the first time, the abs.exe does not exist in my install.

Comment: Great !  But next problem "OPENSSL_Uplink(5F636000,08): no OPENSSL_Applink" that leads me to this link [download another abs.exe on apachelounge](https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=33472)

Comment: OPENSSL_Uplink(000007FEEFE30000,08): no OPENSSL_Applink

Comment: @FrançoisBreton so whats the solution for that problem ? i am using wamp and apache came with it is 2.4.17

Comment: @AMB its been a long time, but I think the solution is to find another abs.exe version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314827

Answer (score 0):

> Usage: C:\Apache24\bin\abs.exe [options]
> [http[s]://]hostname[:port]/path

In my case, I was missing the port

```
./abs.exe -n 100 -c 10 https://somesite:8443.somedomain.com
```

Answer (score -1):

use abs in CMD

example:

abs -n 100 -c 10 https://api.test.com/test-end-point